# PHP variable is empty when called in jQuery script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having a little trouble calling a PHP variable into a jQuery script. Basically, I run a few functions to determine if a user is logged in and, if so, store that as $loggedin=1. If a person that is on a page is NOT logged in, when a button is clicked I want them to be prompted to sign in (I'll obviously still ensure the user is ACTUALLY logged in on the server side before any processing of data). I searched around, and found the easiest way to get that information over to jQuery is to create the script as a PHP file so I can echo it into the script. Here is the high level code I'm using:

Call up the script:

```
<?php
 $loggedIn = 1;
 <script src="../buttonScript.php"></script>
?>
```

Script:

```
<?php header("Content-type: application/javascript"); ?>
var buttonScript = function(){
 var loggedIn = <?php if($loggedIn===1){echo "1";}else{echo "0";} ?>;
  $("#button").click(function(){
  alert(loggedIn);
 });
};

$(document).ready(buttonScript);
```

When I click the button in a situation where $loggedIn is equal to 1, the alert gives me 0. In fact, if I simply echo $loggedIn in the script itself, the value is completely empty and the script errors out and won't pop up an alert at all. I'm confident that the PHP variable $loggedIn actually has a variable, since if I echo the variable right before the script is called, I successfully see the number 1. What am I missing here?

Note: added a couple lines in the script calling just for clarity.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: how do you assign a value to `$loggedIn`? Without that code the question is incomplete.

Comment: A file like `buttonScript.php` won't get interpreted by the Javascript engine?

Comment: seems right, open the file url in browser and see if output is as expected

Comment: @HaigBedrosian - the error only appears when I echo "$loggedIn" directly - I only see the error when using the browser debugging feature. It says I have an unnecessary semicolon. This only appears when the line of the script is `var loggedIn = <?php echo $loggedIn; ?>;` which ends up showing up as `var loggedIn = ;`

Comment: @Krumia '$loggedIn' is set via another script that is called earlier in the page loading process. It contains hundreds of lines of code - all dealing with security of my specific site, so I prefer to avoid posting that here. It is also a bit irrelevant, as I've tested that $loggedIn contains the expected value since I've outputted it to the browser immediately before the script is loaded.

Comment: Try writing like: var loggedIn = '<?php if($loggedIn===1){echo "1";}else{echo "0";} ?>'; - In quotes.

Comment: Try setting `$loggedIn` to a session variable from that _other_ page, and using the session variable there. If it works, then it should be a variable scoping issue.

Comment: @herr thanks, but same result. It still gives tells me "0" even though `$loggedIn` is set to 1.

Comment: But I hope error will not there. If right then try  @Krumia solution using session.

Comment: @Krumia I set a session variable immediately before calling up the script (and modified the variable in the script), but it still comes back empty.

Comment: The script that calculates values for `$loggedIn`, is it `include`d in `buttonscript.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
 $loggedIn = 1;
 require("/path/buttonScript.php");
?>
```

**buttonScript.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var buttonScript = function(){
 var loggedIn = <?php echo $loggedIn; ?>;
  $("#button").click(function(){
  alert(loggedIn);
 });
};

$(document).ready(buttonScript);
</script>
```